# Visual Studio deleted all my contextmenustrips and menustrips. How to recover?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I use C# with Visual Studio and Winforms. Every time I click on the designer it resfreshes the form and sometimes it doesn't load so I have to close the tab and re-open it to load properly. Sometimes when load the tab it removes all my ContextMenuStrips  my menustrip's items get deleted too (all other controls remain) and when I start the app it gives errors "object not set to an instance of an object". This happened 3 times to far and I'm really angry at this bug because I have to recreate them again... The frustrating part is that they are a lot. So when they get deleted, they still stay defined in the designer, but no longer have instances and are not connected to their methods, and if I instantiate them manually in the constructor they appear empy, without items.
()
Please give me some solution to recover this without having to recreate them anew. I don't know when VS will do this again and I will lose my progress again and make them all anew with their methods again.......

I tried in the designer InitializeComponent() to add "this.Controls.Add(menu_cameras);", but when i load the design it doesnt appear, and  when load back the designer, what I wrote got deleted!

using VS 2022

Comment: Hard to help without seeing the project.  To get around the issue, don't use the designer.  Just create the menus through code in the constructor.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [How to report a problem for Visual Studio and Visual Studio Installer](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report)

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Ensure you create a backup of the solution folder periodically (or use source control).  If the issue happens again, one may try closing Visual Studio, then delete the _.vs_ folder within the solution folder. Also, delete the _bin_ and _obj_ folders for each project. The folders (and it's contents) will be re-created.

Comment: That means you have a control/ToolStripItem/component throws a silent exception or an exception that the designer just swallows it and the `InitializeComponent()` method doesn't executed successfully. Run a second Visual Studio instance, hit the `Continue with code` link, attach the second instance to the first one, close and reopen the designer. The second instance would catch the exceptions if anything went wrong. If nothing, keep working with the designer, open the menus and select the items ...etc. You'll get something if any.

Comment: Hello, I searched a lot of information. Most of these situations can be solved by repairing Visual Studio through the Visual Studio installer or updating to the latest version of Visual Studio. If it doesn't work and it is confirmed that it is a problem with Visual Studio itself, you can go to [Visual Studio Feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio) for help.